# How to re-use types when generating code from different swagger files

Tags: c#, rest, swagger, jsonschema, nswag

I own multiple rest services which are described by multiple swagger documents.

The services share some common DTO classes.
Currently, the common DTO classes are included in definitions in each swagger documents.

I would like to generate client C# code from the swagger documents so that the common classes won't be genereated multiple times.

Comment: Well, you're using nswag for this. nswag does not support reuse of types. So no, you can't. You will need to manually hack the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NSwag.Core library to read all documents and merge them into one (your work) then you can generate code from the merged document.